# Hibernate: Call getters on saved object before transaction commit and session close

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have 2 Hibernate Entities A and B:

```
public class A implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
  private Integer id;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a")
  B b;

  // ctors, getters, setters
}

public class B implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
  private Integer id;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn
  A a;  

  // ctors, getters, setters 
}
```

When I create and save these objects, I create both at the same time. After creating them, I would like to call a.getB(), but this returns null. If I commit the transaction, open a new session, and load A, then a.getB() returns b correctly.

This doesn't work:

```
public void doSave() {
  Session session = getSessionFactoryFromSomewhere.openSession();
  session.beginTransaction();
  A a = new A();
  B b = new B();
  b.setA(a);
  session.save(a);
  session.save(b);

  A aFromDb = (A) session.load(A.class, a.getId());
  B bFromA = aFromDb.getB(); // bFromA is null in this case!
}
```

This does work:

```
public void doSave() {
  Session session = getSessionFactoryFromSomewhere().openSession();
  Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
  A a = new A();
  B b = new B();
  b.setA(a);
  session.save(a);
  session.save(b);

  tx.commit();
  session = getSessionFactoryFromSomewhere().openSession();
  tx = session.beginTransaction();

  A aFromDb = (A) session.load(A.class, a.getId());
  B bFromA = aFromDb.getB(); // bFromA is equal to b, which is correct.
}
```

How can I make a.getB() return b without committing the transaction, closing the session, and starting a new session+transaction?

Answer (score 0):

in a `one-to-one` association between two entities if you want to get each object from the other one without committing the transaction or closing and reopening the session, you need to add objects to both side try this one:

```
 A a = new A();
 B b = new B();
 b.setA(a);
 a.setB(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `session.flush()` after you save the entities in session but before you query the database again to see the updated entities.